# Non-owning pointer as class member in modern c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, unique-ptr

I have been researching smart pointers and when they should be used vs raw pointers. My take away was that objects which OWN the pointer should instantiate that pointer as a smart pointer (unique_ptr/shared_ptr).

Then, when passing that pointer to various functions / classes that do not require ownership of it, pass a raw pointer (obtained from the smart pointer via `.get()`) with the caveat that the function / class that the raw pointer is sent to will NEVER outlive the scope of the function / class which owns it.

Is this understanding correct? It seems to make sense to me, but when I started to implement a specific routine my confidence dwindled.

The following code will better explain where my hangup is currently. I have a member vector of `unique_ptr`s to `Mesh` objects in `Scene`. I then pass the raw pointer of the created `unique_ptr` to instantiate an `Actor` object and finally move the `unique_ptr` into the `scene->meshes` vector.

Is the fact that an `Actor` has a `Mesh*` as a member not considered bad practice as long as the scope of any one `Actor` will never outlive that of the owning `scene->meshes` element?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Mesh
{
public:
    int vec = 1;
    int ind = 2;
};

class Actor
{
private:
    Mesh * mesh;
public:
    Actor(Mesh* m) {
        this->mesh = m;
    }
};

class Scene
{
public:
    // meshes will always outlive all instantiated actors
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> meshes;
    std::vector<Actor> actors;
};


int main()
{
    auto scene = std::make_unique<Scene>();

    auto m1 = std::make_unique<Mesh>();
    auto a1 = Actor(m1.get());
    scene->meshes.push_back(std::move(m1));

    auto m2 = std::make_unique<Mesh>();
    auto a2 = Actor(m2.get());
    scene->meshes.push_back(std::move(m2));

    std::cout << scene->meshes.size();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Raw *non owning* pointers are fine IMHO, as long as you *know* that the object they point to always lives longer than the raw pointer.

Comment: To follow up @JesperJuhl point, entry from C++ Core Guidelines, R.3: A raw pointer (a T*) is non-owning: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-ptr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the fact that an Actor has a Mesh* as a member not considered bad practice as long as ...

It is a code smell, sure. The class is easy to misuse. It has to be carefully documented that the constructor stores the pointer for the lifetime of the actor to alert the user to maintain the lifetime of the pointed mesh.

In case such as this, shared ownership would be safer. But it is not always the best choice if the performance overhead is significant.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but very ugly.

You could consider a third class implementing the relationship, and any actions acting on this relationship.

A  [Controller](http://www.tedfelix.com/software/oo.html) of sorts.