# In *modern* C++ how should I manage *unowned* pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In *modern* C++ how should I manage *unowned* pointers?
I was thinking something like a `weak_ptr` for `unique_ptr`, but that doesn't seem to exist.

### Example

For instance, if I have a class `A` that owns a pointer, I should use `unique_ptr<X>` instead of an old `X*` pointer, e.g.

```
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<X> _myX;
};
```

But then if I have another class `B` that uses this pointer, what do I do here? With C style pointers I would do this:

```
class B
{
    X* _someX;
};
```

That seems correct, but it isn't obvious from the code that I've referenced another object's pointer (for instance a reader may think I could have just not used a smart pointer).

### I have considered the following

- `std::shared_ptr<X>` - seems like a waste of reference counting because `A` is guaranteed to outlive `B`.
- `std::weak_ptr<X>` - only works with `shared_ptr`
- `X&` - only works if X& is available in B's constructor

This seems like an obvious issue and sorry if it's been asked before. I've looked around and I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174402/non-owning-pointer-as-class-member-in-modern-c) question, but unfortunately the OP asked "is it OK to use X*" in one specific case. I'm looking for what I should generally be doing *instead* of X*, (if anything!).

Comment: A raw pointer inherently means you have a non-owning pointer, so there is nothing to add or do. In other words let class `B` carry a raw pointer, which expresses that you have no hand in managing the memory of that object.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a related historical curiosity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862412/use-of-observer-ptr

Comment: You're going to find opinions around this, but the other main option people use is a different spelling for the same thing purely to convey intent (such as `observer_ptr`, though some things use an alias and some use a separate type).

Comment: manage ownership, not pointers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup has [weighed in on this matter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf).

> Pointers are really good at pointing to "things" and **T*** is a really good notation for that ... What pointers are not good at is representing ownership

He makes two suggestions:

- Consider `T*` to mean "non-owning pointer to `T`" in modern C++
- Use `template<typename T> using observer_ptr = T*;` if you desire your variable declarations to *explicitly document* this non-ownership.

Comment: There are considerations for template class for `observer_ptr` instead of an alias to raw pointer. As this changes type as well which has purpose.

Comment: This is a bad implementation of `observer_ptr`. Experimental has a better one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr

Comment: @SergeyA "better" is debatable - that's the same `observer_ptr` Stroustrup spends 3  pages lambasting in the document, concluding by suggesting the alternative version posted by Drew.

Answer (score 4):

> That seems correct, but it isn't obvious from the code that I've referenced another object's pointer

Ideally, it *should* be obvious. If the pointer owned the resource, then it should have been a smart pointer. Since it isn't a smart pointer, that implies that it shouldn't own the resource.

That said, in the reality that has C / ancient C++ / badly designed interfaces which use owning pointers, you can clarify the lack of ownership like this:

```
class B
{
    X* _someX; // no ownership
};
```

---

It is also possible to define a custom class template wrapper for this purpose, and there has been a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf) to include such template in the standard library, which was adopted as a technical specification, but has not been adopted into the standard proper. To my understanding, there's no consensus on whether such wrapper is useful or unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is largely opinion based, but we can take a look at what the core guideline has to say about it:

> [R.3: A raw pointer (a T*) is non-owning](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning)
>
> Reason
>
> There is nothing (in the C++ standard or in most code) to say otherwise and most raw pointers are non-owning. We want owning pointers identified so that we can reliably and efficiently delete the objects pointed to by owning pointers.

The guideline promotes to never use a raw pointer when it is an owning pointer. Once you do that, a raw pointer also readily signals that it is non-owning. The downside of this interpretation is:

> Exception
>
> A major class of exception is legacy code, especially code that must remain compilable as C or interface with C and C-style C++ through ABIs. The fact that there are billions of lines of code that violate this rule against owning T*s cannot be ignored. [...]

Not all raw pointers are non-owning, and often we cannot do much about that. However, if your code is written after C++11, then using a raw pointer should be sufficient to signal that it is not an owning pointer.

Comment: @eerorika the last part was written in a rush. I will remove it until I can fix it

Answer (score 1):

https://abseil.io/tips/116 is a good discussion of the options here.  If you have the thing at construction time, and never need to repoint it, then `T&` is probably good.  If you don't, then "hey this might be null" is part of reality for that pointer, and `T*` is fine - a "raw" pointer in modern C++ generally communicates an optional, non-owning reference.